# Can not prevent form submit when I add one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am stacked. My code can not prevent defaut action of submit. This was working fine until I add `this.doSomething();`.

Why this happens? Do I have to use preventDefault?

working code: http://jsfiddle.net/WwW5R/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <form action="" method="post" id="input">
            <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var ReserveUI = function($el) {
        this.$form = {
            input: $el.find('#input')
        };
        this._eventify();
    };

    ReserveUI.prototype.doSomething = function() {
        return false;
    }

    ReserveUI.prototype._eventify = function() {
        this.$form.input.submit(function() {
            this.doSomething(); //if comment out this line, it works
            return false;
        });
    };
    var UI = new ReserveUI($("#container"));
});
```

thanks for reading:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `submit` callback function, `this` no longer refers to your object, but to the element itself.

It's therefore causing an exception because the element has no `doSomething` property, and your `return false` is skipped.

Instead, write this:

```
ReserveUI.prototype._eventify = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$form.input.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // cancels event even if subsequent lines fail
        self.doSomething();
    });
};
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/xgGGx/1/ for a working example showing that it's just the scope issue causing the bug.

This is what script debugging tools are for - the reported error should have made the fault reasonably obvious...

Comment: How could _return false;_ cause an exception in this case?

Comment: No, check the example: it's the same yet doesn't work. adding `e.preventDefault` works as expected.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment why do you believe that?  Notwithstanding that `e.preventDefault()` isn't a bad idea, he still has a `this` scoping problem.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment putting `e.preventDefault()` fixes the event handling issue - it won't fix the problem with `.doSomething()` not actually getting called.

Comment: @ downvoter - please look again, you can't have read my answer properly.

Comment: Alnitak, it's thanks to you that now I understand my scope problem. I had the idea of using preventDefault, but find another way it if possible(I don't think it's a bad way). thanks a lot!

Comment: @tosin actually using `e.preventDefault()` is generally considered best practise for just this sort of reason.  Starx's answer cam somewhat after mine, but without using `preventDefault`.

Comment: Why `e.preventDefault()` is considered to best practise?

Comment: @tosin precisely because putting `e.preventDefault()` at the top of your callback ensures that the default never happens, but a `return false` can end up being ignored, as you saw.

Comment: @Alnitak I see, it's sure. And for code reading, "return false" cannot obviously be read as "prevent default action", not good(at least in my case). I just understood. thanks

Comment: @tosin the other reason is that `return false` is a jQuery special fix up.  jQuery wraps event handlers in a function that automatically calls `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` if (and only if) the callback returns false.  However if you bind event handlers outside of jQuery (e.g. using `addEventListener`) you _have_ to use `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a scope mismatch.

```
this.$form.input.submit(function() { //here "this" is ReserveUI
    this.doSomething(); //here "this" is input button
    return false;
});
```

And since there is no `doSomething()` on `input` button, the script breaks thus no longer executing the portion to `return false`.

Here is a way you can get around this

```
ReserveUI.prototype._eventify = function() {
    var $this = this; //create a reference to the object
    this.$form.input.submit(function() {
        $this.doSomething(); //Now call the object method
        return false;
    });
};
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WwW5R/11/)

Comment: except I think you got your last sentence the wrong way around

Comment: Glad to keep using "return false"! The reason I prefer to use it is that keeps code clear. thanks for smart answer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there's an error in your `doSomething` code (which I assume isn't just `return false` in your program).

To ensure the event does not continue, even if there's an error, do not return false but use `e.preventDefault()` instead:

```
    this.$form.input.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.doSomething();
    });
```

Comment: His `doSomething ` function only has `return false` in its body.

Comment: I guess he just removed his actual code. The function doesn't make much sense with `return false`.

Comment: @Sarfraz True but this is still the approach the user should take to cancel event default behaviour and is call to this.doSomething() is wrong as this is not what it expect.

Comment: thanks for answer. but I don't remove actual code. I will write something instead of doSomething(); in future. This code is for study.